# NatTable-Setting a Dynamic Column Width

Tags: java, nattable

I would like to have the columns of a NatTable dynamically expand to

- show the entire value in the cell
- completely fill the parent composite

It seems I can do one or the other, but not both.  In other words, if I have a large parent Composite and the NatTable has only a few columns with very short values, I will have a lot of blank space (aka the NatTable will have a small width in comparison to the parent Composites width)

I have tried the following code snippets:

```
// This sets the full width of the Composite, but all columns are equal 
// width. If a column has a long value, the value will be truncated.
glazedListsGridLayer.getBodyDataLayer().setColumnPercentageSizing(true);

// This auto-resizes the columns based on their values. If the values
// are short, this table will not fill the width of the composite
nattable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration() { {
  cellPainter = new LineBorderDecorator(new TextPainter(false, true, 5, true));}
});
```

I guess I am looking for a hybrid where the columns will be auto-resized based on the value. If the table does not fill the width of the composite I would like either:

- All columns add additional width evenly until the table is the same size as the Composite parent or
- A particular column will add the extra width until the table is the same size as the Composite parent

If the table fills the entire width of the Composite and the column values are long, I would like to ensure the table has a horizontal scrollbar (when necessary) to see all the columns and their non-truncated values

Does anyone have any insight as to how to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: You are basically asking for something like a minimum column width setting which is as far as I know currently not supported out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying a min width is currently not supported. But if it is only a visual thing you could try to use the `NatGridLayerPainter` that prints on the whole available space. This is like an additional column but actually without adding a column.

```
NatTable natTable = new NatTable(parent);
NatGridLayerPainter layerPainter = new NatGridLayerPainter(natTable);
natTable.setLayerPainter(layerPainter);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't seem to do much. It added vertical depth, but not horizontal. I also tried it in tandem with the other code snippets in my original post but no luck.  Am I supposed to override the layerPainter or do more with it than your code snippet provides? Thanks!

Comment: For your use case you need to combine it with the TextPainter that calculates the width from your original post. If you also want to add fake rows you need to create the NatGridLayerPainter wit a second parameter for the fake row height.

Comment: I tried using the TextPainter snippet shown above (as is) alongside your snippet (as is) and no luck.  I should mention that when the table originally displays it has no rows (and relies on the column header length). It does not span the width of the Composite as I'd like. Once rows come in, it resizes as I'd expect, but it never fills the Composite parent width.

Comment: Sorry I don't get your usecase an requirement in detail. Probably it is simply not supported in the combination you are looking for it. Percentage sizing that automatically takes the whole space is limited to rely on the available space. The automatic width calculation does not work in combination with percentage sizing. So the only way to do something like that is to tell your data provider that there is an additional empty column that is solely configured for percentage sizing. Not sure if that would work though.

Comment: I don't know if it would help but I uploaded a screenshots of what I'm looking at. 
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2d9wg2s&s=9

and

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=156ep8k&s=9

I'd ideally like both pics to take on the entire width of the composite parent

Comment: Actually it takes the whole width. What doesn't work is rendering the column header accordingly. You could try to extend the painter to do that also.

Comment: I've looked around a bit but I don't see exactly how to do that. Is there any examples that can help with setting the column header width?

Comment: The column header width is derived from the body. You somehow need to render a fake column header for the fake column. And no there is no example for that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by fake. Why would I have a fake column header and a fake column? What about the real columns? How would they work in tandem?

Comment: You asked for that to take the whole available space. And this is what the NatGridLayerPainter is actually doing.

Comment: I think I'm more confused now. I want the column widths to take up the entire space of the parent width. A quick look at the source code for the NatGridLayerPainter seems to deal with row heights. I do not understand the terminology 'fake headers' and 'fake columns'.  The closest thing I found to working is getBodyDataLayer().setDefaultColumnWidth((int)parentWidth/numOfColumns); followed by cellPainter code shown in the original post. As long as the user can't resize columns, this seems a very cludgy way of getting close to what I want

Comment: Maybe you should read again your question. There you asked as an alternative that uses an extra column, and the NatGridLayerPainter adds a fake column to achieve that. You see this if the parent Composite is bigger than the table. But breaking it up again: every column should take the maximum available space = percentage sizing, every column should have a width that automatically shows all content = TextPainter calculateHeight, combining both percentage sizing and auto sizing = not supported!, specify a minimum width for columns = not supported!

Comment: I re-read my original post and do not see anything about additional columns. In the 2nd bullet point I meant that one of the existing columns should take on the additional width. Either way, thanks for helping out and letting me know what features are supported. I may add a resize-window listener on the parent and call setDefaultColumnWidth when that occurs. I will use that in tandem with the cell painter code